# Vim Syntastic not jumping to the error

Tags: vim, syntastic

I'm using ESLint with Syntastic in Vim. Errors are found correctly in Syntastic, but when I navigate to the error in the Error Location Panel, and hit Enter, it drops me off in the same position I was in in the file, instead of taking me to the correct line and column.

I see the following error as well:

`E926: Current location list was changed`

However, my Google-fu finds nothing on this error.

I also recorded a quick screencast demonstrating this happening:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6qjh2mk4g5w63c/syntastic%20not%20working.mov?dl=0

Any thoughts on how to resolve this? It was working a few weeks; I haven't changed my .vimrc but I did reinstall node & npm recently.

-- Update --

Output from `brew info vim`:

`vim: stable 7.4.1655, HEAD
Vi "workalike" with many additional features
http://www.vim.org/
Conflicts with: ex-vi
/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1655 (1,625 files, 22.5M) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/vim.rb
==> Dependencies
Optional: lua ✘, luajit ✘
==> Options
--disable-nls
        Build vim without National Language Support (translated messages, keymaps)
--override-system-vi
        Override system vi
--with-client-server
        Enable client/server mode
--with-lua
        Build vim with lua support
--with-luajit
        Build with luajit support
--with-mzscheme
        Build vim with mzscheme support
--with-python3
        Build vim with python3 instead of python[2] support
--with-tcl
        Build vim with tcl support
--without-perl
        Build vim without perl support
--without-python
        Build vim without python support
--without-ruby
        Build vim without ruby support
--HEAD
        Install HEAD version`

Comment: This is the only hit I'm finding for the issue as well, issue seems to have just started very recently. A little [info on the error code here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/ffec3c53496d49668669deabc0724ec78e2274fd/runtime/doc/quickfix.txt). I tried checking out syntastic commits from a full year ago and the bug remained -- perhaps it's an issue with an update to vim? Also, `:lnext` and `:lprev` still work for me, just not navigating from the list. Do you happen to be on OS X using Homebrew?

Comment: `:lnext` and `:lprev` both work for me fine. I'm on OS X 10.11.4 and yeah, using Homebrew.

Comment: Good thing you guys reported this problem on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues) instead of waiting for it to solve itself by magic.  Wait, never mind.  Please upgrade syntastic to 7e986f1 or later, and try your scenario again.  Report any remaining issues (to the issue tracker this time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be due to a problem with vim (I'm not sure what), introduced between 7.4.1589 and 7.4.1655. If you're using OS X / Homebrew, a temporary solution may be to `brew switch vim 7.4.1589` (assuming you still have the local copy of that version downloaded, you can check with `brew info vim`).

If you don't have that version listed under `brew info vim`, you can install it directly from the commit's URL:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/7746a5509b3fb10216f1d40ab639398e8d0c5e4c/Library/Formula/vim.rb
```

Alternatively, you can do it locally by searching the homebrew git logs for the commit you need and reverting the vim formula to that commit:

```
git -C "$(brew --repository)" log --grep='vim 7.4.1589'

# Using the commit from the above command
git -C "$(brew --repository)" checkout 7746a5509b3fb10216f1d40ab639398e8d0c5e4c -- Library/Formula/vim.rb

# Ensure the version number looks correct
head <"$(brew --repository)"/Library/Formula/vim.rb

# Install as usual
brew install vim

# Later, when you're ready to go back to the latest version
git -C "$(brew --repository)" checkout HEAD .
```

You can also leave out all the `-C "$(brew --repository)"` stuff if you just `cd "$(brew --repository)"` at the beginning.

Comment: I am on `7.4.1655`. Do you have any recommendations on how to install a specific version with homebrew? It seems like there's conflicting advice (one answer says to `tap homebrew/boneyard`, another says `tap homebrew/versions` - neither seems to work).

Comment: Did you try the commands I listed above to see if it was already installed? It doesn't clean out old versions automatically, so unless you removed it, it's probably still there.

Comment: I don't believe I have it installed; I posted the output from `brew info vim` in the original answer so I could format it nicely.

Comment: Updated with a few different ways. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much n8henrie. I had to do a `brew unlink vim` at the beginning as well (before `brew install http...`). Syntastic is now working again.

Comment: Still an issue in 7.4.1707.

Comment: Please see [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1738).

Comment: `:PluginUpdate` was the last step that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better solution, then pinnin vim would be updating your syntastic. See https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/1738 The issue has been fixed in https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/commit/d9814c5233931bb111fcae7cdc623a9f29495e5d